# Is Tridion Docs Taxonomy Connector compatible with older version of SDL Web

Tags: taxonomy, tridion-docs

For SDL Tridion Docs 13 SP2, is the [taxonomy connector](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-97ACE388-172A-4E53-806A-4E86DD2A3F11&addHistory=true&query=taxonomy%2520connector&scope=&tid=b960ef7f-6cbd-4605-bcee-b217273584f0&filename=GUID-97ACE388-172A-4E53-806A-4E86DD2A3F11.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-97ACE388-172A-4E53-806A-4E86DD2A3F11&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtaxonomy%2520connector&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1560287835839&currentQuery=taxonomy%2520connector&currentScope=) compatible with older versions than Sites 9 (i.e SDL Web 8.5, SDL Web 8.1, etc.)?

As far as I can tell, there is no mention of version compatibility, although it says say "SDL Tridion Sites," which may imply Sites 9. I did a quick test with Web 8.5 and it seems to be working (although my test was not all that thorough - I just made sure I could get basic keywords from Sites displayed in the Docs properties metadata fields). I need to know if this is going to work with Web 8.1 and if it has any known issues or other quirks.

Comment: I just ran another test with Web 8.1 and it seems there is an incompatibility caused by Web 8.1 only having CoreService201501.svc, but the Taxonomy Connector expecting a CoreService201603.svc endpoint. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

The Taxonomy Connector is part of the Tridion DX suite, which is a combination of Tridion Sites and Docs.

Tridion Sites 9.0 in combination with Docs 13 SP2 (and UDP/DXD 11.0) forms the first version of this Tridion DX suite.

Can you elaborate on your use case for the Taxonomy Connector for SDL Web 8?

Comment: We have a client that is using Web 8.1 and Docs 13 SP2. They to manage taxonomies in their Web 8.1 instance that can be connected into their Docs 13 SP2 instance.

The only solution I can think of is to re-implement the taxonomy connector to work with the available core service in Web 8.1, which is a shame, since we don't have access to any code for the taxonomy connector...

Comment: I can think of another solution: convince the client to upgrade to Sites 9. :-). The use case is still not clear to me, but it seems like your client wants to do some kind of “content mashup” (combining content from Tridion Sites and Docs). We developed the Tridion DX suite for that purpose.

Comment: Does your client realize that Web 8.1 is EOL, so further investment in it may not be the smartest thing to do?